# How do dll's get referenced in 2nd tier projects

Tags: c#, dll

I know the title might be kind of obscure, but I have no better way to word it.

I have a project named **TestProject** which uses a dll named **BusinessCode**.

BusinessCode is referenced in TestProject and so is copied to the Debug folder of the TestProject (Copy Local = True). This is what I call my 1st tier referencing.

My 2nd tier are the dll's referenced in BusinessCode. These dll's are **LanguageProvider** and **System.Data.SQLite**. LanguageProvider only has resource dictionaries in it so no hard code is written to the dll, I can even leave it out of the reference as long as I copy the dll to the Debug folder of the BusinessCode dll. But here comes the stuff I don't fully understand. Wether or not I reference LanguageProvider in BusinessCode, LanguageProvider never get's copied to the 1st tier (TestProject) Debug folder.

On the other hand, System.Data.SQLite must be referenced in BusinessCode. However, if I use code in BusinessCode, System.Data.SQLite will also be copied to the 1st tier (TestProject) Debug folder. If I don't use code it will not.

What I learn from this is that dll's don;t get copied to higher tiers if they're not required to. What I'm wondering is, how is this controlled? How does VS2015 know when or when not to do this? The reason for me asking is that I'd like to reference LanguageProvider in BusinessCode but that it also get's copied to the 1st tier (TestProject) Debug folder.